# Error while traversing Null array in DRools rule

Tags: java, drools

I am using arrayList in .drl rule file.
In one rule i am checking list is null or not and setting setFocus(2nd rule) .
in 2nd rule i am getting the element from list, bt in this rule i am getting list is null error.

I want to check list is null or not and getting particular element from that arraylist in one rule.

```
rule "Rule chesks client had already received Notifications or Not" 
salience 10   
no-loop true
when  
    event : Event($listOfClientNotifications : clientNotifications)
    eval($listOfClientNotifications < 1)   
then
    event.setMessage("list is null");
end
```

2nd rule:

```
rule "Rule chesks " 
salience 05   
no-loop true
when  
    event : Event($listOfClientNotifications : clientNotifications)
    value : ClientNotifications() from $listOfClientNotifications; // <<< !!!
then  
    event.setMessage("Value "+**value.getMessage()**);
end
```

This `<<< !!!` is where the null error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Testing a list (correctly!) against null in one rule doesn't avoid running into a NPE in another rule. Rule evaluations are *not*, repeat *not*, synchronized with rule executions, salience and activations groups notwithstanding.

This is a correct check:

```
rule "check list is null"
when  
    event : Event(clientNotifications == null)
then
    event.setMessage("list is null");
end
```

Guard against running into NPE

```
rule "use notifications from list"
when  
    event : Event($listOfClientNotifications : clientNotifications != null)
    value : ClientNotifications() from $listOfClientNotifications;
then  
    event.setMessage("Value "+ value.getMessage()); // strange, but maybe?
end
```